# Random OpenLdap Timeout Issue

Tags: openldap

I am am currently running OpenLdap 2.4.31 on Ubuntu 12.04 in EC2. I am having an issue where I get random timeouts when doing ldapsearch or ldapadd commands against the ldap server.

There is really no load against the ldap servers, I am using them for name resolution for EC2 internal hostnames and using ldap as an external node classifier for puppet.

When the timeout happens I get the following error:

ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server

If I rerun the command it works fine, this is causing some issues in my automation (and while I can put in error checking for this it seems odd its happening in the first place).

Here is a copy of my slapd.conf (with some env specific info commented out) hopefully someone has some suggestions on what I am missing in the config to prevent the timeout issue:

```
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
        include /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/etc/openldap/schema/puppet.schema
        pidfile         /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/var/run/slapd.pid
        argsfile        /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/var/run/slapd.args
        loglevel 0
        serverID 001
        database bdb
        suffix    "dc=example,dc=local"
        rootdn    "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local"
        rootpw    secret
        directory /opt/openldap/openldap-2.4.31/var/openldap-data
        idletimeout 120
        timelimit 300
        cachesize 2000
        syncrepl rid=000
          provider=ldap://10.10.10.10
          type=refreshAndPersist
          retry="5 5 10 +"
          searchbase="dc=example,dc=local"
          attrs="*,+"
          bindmethod=simple
          binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local"
          credentials=secret
        syncrepl rid=000
          provider=ldap://10.10.10.20
          type=refreshAndPersist
          retry="5 5 10 +"
          searchbase="dc=example,dc=local"
          attrs="*,+"
          bindmethod=simple
          binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local"
          credentials=secret
        index entryCSN eq
        index entryUUID eq
        mirrormode TRUE
        overlay syncprov
        syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
```

Comment: I enabled debug and I see this message pretty often in the log:

slapd[311]: daemon: shutdown requested and initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore this question. My self-healing automation was misconfiguration and was restarting the slapd process every minute on accident.